# Python Pandas Groupby to count unique records in a single column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df having a single column containing rows of repeating data. I want to display a pivot table of unique values of that column along with their count. I know it would be some sort of groupby however I could not get it to work, please help.

[image: My df]. [image: Desired output]

Comment: `df['PdDistrict'].value_counts().reset_index()`. To plot: `df['PdDistrict'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby("PdDistrict").size()
```

Comment: Thank you @Pablo C, it works. how do I add column names (PdDistrict and count?)

Comment: Actually nvm, I got it
df2.rename(columns={'PdDistrict': 'Counts'}, inplace=True)
df2
df2.index.name = 'Neighbourhood'
df2